# copy files only not directory structure using powershell

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I am having a hard time using Copy-item  for copying files(only) recursively with a particular extension(*.txt) without the directory structure. Can anyone please give me a hand? I have used the the gci with -recurse and piped the output to copy-item, it gives an error saying improper input. `Get-ChildItem -Path $source -include "*name*.txt" -recurse | Copy-Item $source $dest`

Comment: How do you want to handle filename collisions?

Comment: The destination directory is empty.

Comment: I am not worried about the repeated filenames as well, I had already put the full path and filename in a .csv

Answer (score 0):

Use -file for take only file and not directory. Copy-item into pipe must have only destination path... -force if doublon file

try this:

```
gci $source -file -include "*name*.txt" -recurse | copy-item -Destination $dest -Force
```

if you have doublon you can try this :

```
$source="C:\temp\Release"
$dest="c:\temp\x"
gci $source -file -include "*name*.txt" -recurse | group Name | %{

  for ($i = 0; $i -lt $_.Count; $i++)
  { 
    if ($_.Count -gt 1)
    {
        $destination="{0}\{1}_{2}" -f $dest, $i, $_.Group[$i].Name
    }
    else
    {
        $destination="{0}\{1}" -f $dest, $_.Group[$i].Name
    }

    copy-item $_.Group[$i].FullName $destination -WhatIf -Force 

  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Esperento57. It was helpful but duplicate filenames were ignored. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Look my post for doublon ;)

Comment: Hey, Esperento57. It doesn't copy the files although I can see the -whatif trace. Thank you though man.